# Publish a Service Fabric Container project

Tags: docker-compose, azure-service-fabric, docker-container

I don't make it to publish a container. In my case I want to put an MVC4 Webrole into the container. ...but actually, what's inside the container does not matter.

1. Their [primary tutorial for using a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-host-app-in-a-container) to lift-and-shift old apps uses Continuous Delivery. The average user does not always need this.
2. Instead of Continuous Delivery one may use the Visual Studio's support for Docker Compose:
   `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster <mycluster>` and then `New-ServiceFabricComposeApplication -ApplicationName> <mytestapp> -Compose docker-compose.yml`

   But following exactly [their tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-docker-compose) still leads to errors. The applicaton appears in the cluster but outputs immediatly an error event:

   > "SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Download:1.0:1.0'. Error during
   >   download. Failed to download container image fabrikamfiber.web"

Do I miss a whole step, which they expect to be obvious? But even placing the image in my Docker Hub registry myself did not help? Or does it need to be [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/)?

Comment: Docker Hub should work fine, ACR is not required. Maybe these blog posts help: http://blog.sluijsveld.com/20/05/2017/DeployingDockerComposedAppOnServiceFabric/ and https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/

Comment: How the heck, did you find those. ^^  From them I should be able to get further. You could rewrite your comment as an answer. I linked this thread in the comments of the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: I wrote one, and my colleague wrote the other.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Hub should work fine, ACR is not required. 
These blog posts may help:

- [about running containers](https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/)
- [about docker compose on Service Fabric](http://blog.sluijsveld.com/20/05/2017/DeployingDockerComposedAppOnServiceFabric/)

Comment: What else can go wrong during deployment? I follow _exactly_ your and the microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-containers) but I can just not access the solution on the cluster via `<myapp>.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`. Whatever I do:'Website not reachable'.

Comment: Can you RDP into one of the nodes that run the service and see if it's running ok in there? If so, it may be a simple matter of configuring the Azure Load Balancer.  Can you use the part 2 article to debug? https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric-part-ii/

Comment: Tested it further. Unfortunately I would have to redeploy my cluster. I did not use a template as you can finally select docker supporting VMs directly. Everything should run fine regarding output of SF-Explorer. Is it worth to dedeploy everything to enable RDP? What could be the Load Balancer issue. Did not change anything there since none of the tutorials mentioned that.

Comment: Even [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monub/2017/05/28/docker-blog-series-part-2-build-deploy-asp-net-core-docker-image-on-service-fabric/) 2-step tutorial for publishing a public available docker container does not work. What could be wrong??? My cluster is secure. Changing port to 443 does not help either.

Comment: The load balancer needs to have a load balancing rule for ports 80 and 443. Do you have that?

Comment: Thank you. I exactly found that solution an hour before you postet it. This is somehow nowhere mentioned. They take this as granted. And for public party clusters, this is setup per default, what confuses you even more.

Comment: Unfortunately the struggle continues in the next step...
"403 - Forbidden: Access is denied" output by IIS.

Comment: This error even appears when there is no service published at all.
So the error message is comming from load balancer!??

Comment: I'm getting the same error and read in the blog that I should at lease be running version 255.255.5713.255. Yesterday I've setup a cluster using 'Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with Contianers' and installed the latest version of Service Fabric (CodeVersion 6.0.219.9494). Does anyone know if this problem still exists in this version? If it does, where can I download a preview of Service Fabric?

Comment: I recommend asking a regular question.